# MFC writing double data type to registry

Tags: c++, mfc, registry, double

I'm working on an application that needs to store a data value of type double to the registry.  I'm using MFC but the only functions in "theApp" that I see for doing the job (from the searching that I've done) are `GetProfileIntW`, `GetProfileStringW` and `GetProfileBinary`.  What would be the best way to store and retrieve the data while keeping as much precision as possible?

Comment: Is there some reason not to use the Win32 registry functions directly?

Comment: @CareyGregory, MFC automatically puts your keys in an appropriate spot in the registry. It's just a convenience thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GetProfileBinary function is the only reasonable choice.  Using a string would mean doing conversions and using an int would lose precision in many cases.

```
double *pMyDouble;
UINT size = sizeof(*pMyDouble);
GetProfileBinary(sectionName, valueName, (LPBYTE *)&pMyDouble, &size);
double myDouble = *pMyDouble;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for the third argument:

"Argument type of 'double *' is incompatible with parameter type of 'LPBYTE *'."

Comment: @TimothyChapman Edited again after noticing GetProfileBinary does the unusual thing of returning a pointer to the data in the third parameter rather than returning data to a buffer you provide.  Sorry about that, but it's one of the little things that make me hate the MFC.

Comment: Thanks.  There were no compiling errors.  But I do not yet have enough of the program done to know if this actually worked.  I'll post back when I can put in some sort of test value.

Comment: I don't think there is a 6052 error.  I would suggest posting another question and showing your code.

Comment: Never-mind.  I found out why.  The target registry keys do not exist.  Apparently, (for GetProfileBinary only) I need to have the registry keys in place.  I added the keys manually and your code worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Danger, this produce a memoy leak. missing delete[] myDouble at the end !?

Comment: @TomTom <shrug> It's just a code fragment. It also lacks error checking, so the user has to use their head and add the missing pieces.